# Not able to bifurcate closing balance month-wise

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with merchant name, current balance and date. i want closing balance for every month. i tried this code but this is giving me latest current balance, not the month wise closing balance.

query i'm trying -

```
select 
a.`merchant_name`,
case when date(a.latest) between '2021-05-01' and '2021-05-31' then b.current_balance /* else null */ end  as 'May',
case when date(a.latest) between '2021-06-01' and '2021-06-31' then b.current_balance /* else null */ end  as 'June',
case when date(a.latest) between '2021-07-01' and '2021-07-31' then b.current_balance /* else null */ end  as 'July',
case when date(a.latest) between '2021-08-01' and '2021-08-31' then b.current_balance /* else null */ end  as 'August',
case when date(a.latest) between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-31' then b.current_balance /* else null */ end  as 'September',
case when date(a.latest) between '2021-10-01' and '2021-10-31' then b.current_balance /* else null */ end  as 'October',
case when date(a.latest) between '2021-11-01' and '2021-11-31' then b.current_balance /* else null */ end  as 'November'
from
(
select `merchant_name`,
date(`created_at`) as created_at,
min(`created_at`) as firstt,
current_balance,
max(`created_at`) as latest

from balances os
where `companies_id` in (100001,200002,300003)
group by `companies_id`
)a
inner join balances b on a.latest= b.`created_at` and b.`merchant_name`=a.`merchant_name`;
```

Comment: You are getting the latest month per merchant in the subquery and using it to calculate the sum, so I'm at loss to understand your surprise at getting the latest balance only! If you want monthly sums, then just group by merchant, year and month and sum the values. You should provide sample data, expected output, and actual output gor us to really help you.

Answer (score 0):

Group also by the year/month in the subquery.
But not in the outer query.

```
select 
  a.`merchant_name`
, MAX(case when a.yearmonth = 202105 then b.current_balance end) as `May 2021`
, MAX(case when a.yearmonth = 202106 then b.current_balance end) as `June 2021`
, MAX(case when a.yearmonth = 202107 then b.current_balance end) as `July 21`
, MAX(case when a.yearmonth = 202108 then b.current_balance end) as `August 2021`
, MAX(case when a.yearmonth = 202109 then b.current_balance end) as `September 2021`
, MAX(case when a.yearmonth = 202110 then b.current_balance end) as `October 2021`
, MAX(case when a.yearmonth = 202111 then b.current_balance end) as `November 2021`
from
(
  select `companies_id`, `merchant_name`
  , CAST(DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`,'%Y%m') AS UNSIGNED) as yearmonth
  , max(`created_at`) as latest
  from balances
  where `companies_id` in (100001, 200002, 300003)
  group by `companies_id`, `merchant_name`
  , CAST(DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`,'%Y%m') AS UNSIGNED)
) a
inner join balances b 
  on b.`companies_id` = a.`companies_id`
 and b.`merchant_name` = a.`merchant_name`
 and b.`created_at` = a.latest
group by a.`companies_id`, a.`merchant_name`
```

Comment: Really? Nice! And here I was wondering if this would turn into a discussion to make it work. About stuff like the format not working in your version.